# MPMediaQuery artistsQuery returns duplicates

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmediaquery

I am using the [Apple Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html) in my application. To fetch items I am using the [`MPMediaQuery`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008220) as described in their documents. Which works well, but when using the predefined query to retrieve all artists, I get duplicated entries for few artists.

Can somebody explain why there are duplicates? How do I suppress them?

```
NSArray *collections = [[MPMediaQuery artistsQuery] collections];
```

*(And no there aren't any typos or differences in the casing in the name of the artist!)*

Comment: For starters, there could be some meta that causes duplication. However, to confirm this, how about creating an NSSet using the NSArray which will automatically remove all duplicates? `NSSet *uniqueArtists = [NSSet setWithArray:collections];`. See if this removes the duplicates. Otherwise there must be something that makes the artists duplicate despite same artist name.

Comment: Poorly that's not possible, since I also want to use the sections feature of MPMediaQuery. Yep, but it would be interesting to find out what kind of meta data duplicates them and how to prevent.

Comment: do you see the same duplicate artists in the music app in the artists tab?

Comment: No, there aren't any duplicates in the Music app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed that this occurs only when there are albums with multiple artists.

Instead of just `[MPMediaQuery artistQuery]`, the following pretends this behavior:

```
MPMediaQuery *artistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
artistsQuery.groupingType = MPMediaGroupingAlbumArtist; 
NSArray *collections = [artistQuery collection];
```